# Can I combine my Canon camera with my Nikon flash?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, manual-flash

I have a Canon 60D camera and a SB-600 flash for Nikon. Can I use this flash wirelessly with my camera? I had Nikon camera before which I replaced with Canon and I haven't purchased a flash yet, so this is my only option so far. It would be cool if it worked. I don't care for automatic features (like TTL, etc), I can use the flash in full manual mode, I just need the camera to fire it when taking the photo.

Comment: Is there a reason why you've not sold the SB-600 to buy a Canon flash?  They're holding their value quite well on the s/hand market.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but only with extra gear like radio triggers or an external optical slave. The built-in slave can only operate in Nikon's CLS mode.

Comment: Or alternately, _yes, with extra gear like radio triggers or an external optical slave_. :)

Comment: So can you point me to what I need to buy? I want to go with the cheapest option, I guess that would be a cheap radio trigger from china? I don't know how to look for one, could you give me a start point?

Comment: @RiMMER an optical trigger would be cheaper than radio triggers. You'll need one that can ignore TTL preflashes. Here's a review of several optical triggers with SB-600 - http://dpanswers.com/content/optical_flash.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it as an on-camera flash, but first hide all contacts of hotshoe with cello tape except the centre point. Then you can use any Nikon flash on Canon system in auto and manual mode. Be careful not to use the Auto ISO feature of camera. Set ISO and f stop on flash and camera first, and switch off auto standby option in some flashes like sb600, 800, 900, 910 and enjoy shooting as do I. No problems.